# Why can't I use the module `umap`

Tags: python, linux, package, conda

I try to use the python `umap-learn` package (see [documentation](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap)) on linux.
I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                            File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
import umap.umap_ as umap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'umap'
```

My python code is

```
import umap.umap_ as umap
print(umap)
```

What I tried is to create a new `conda` environment.
As written in the documentation, I run

```
conda install numpy scipy
conda install scikit-learn
conda install numba
pip install umap-learn
```

in the command line.

How can I run this code properly?

Comment: That part of the documentation is for troubleshooting problematic PyPI installations. Instead, just start from Conda, which is what the documentation actually recommends: `conda install -c conda-forge umap-learn`

Answer (score 0):

To install the umap package with conda run one of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge umap-learn
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 umap-learn
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 umap-learn
```